# Android: always show menu bar/static menu bar

Tags: android-layout

I would like to use the menu bar instead of a tab bar (tabs are not made for being at the bottom of the view ...).

Is there any chance to give the menu bar a static behaviour?

Related post:
[android : set the menu out / visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392828/android-set-the-menu-out-visible) with the solution:
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { public void run() { openOptionsMenu(); } }, 2000);

It works fine, but hides away constantly.

Many thankx!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to abuse menu functionalities. What could be the solution: create a vertical LinearLayout with two additional layouts inside. Let the top one have layout_weight="1" and here place your content. In the bottom one place images or buttons or similar, which you could make look like tab options or whatever you want.